# java script bring a nested object up to the root level

Tags: javascript, lodash

I got a json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "total": 298,
  "max_score": 5.2472496,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "kafkajmx2",
      "_type": "logs",
      "_id": "AVo-VsUdponm9zQGYYS5",
      "_score": 5.2472496,
      "_source": {
        "metric_value_number": 134,
        "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
        "@timestamp": "2017-02-14T20:35:58.266Z",
        "metric_name": "IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
        "@version": "1",
        "host": "localhost",
        "metric_type": "ReplicaManager",
        "metric_path": "node1.kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
        "type": null,
        "metric_node": "node1.kafka.server"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "kafkajmx2",
      "_type": "logs",
      "_id": "AVo-V69Yponm9zQGYYwS",
      "_score": 5.2472496,
      "_source": {
        "metric_value_number": 134,
        "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
        "@timestamp": "2017-02-14T20:36:58.216Z",
        "metric_name": "IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
        "@version": "1",
        "host": "localhost",
        "metric_type": "ReplicaManager",
        "metric_path": "node1.kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
        "type": null,
        "metric_node": "node1.kafka.server"
      }
    }
]
}
```

what I want to do is bring up the `_source` object to the root level to looks like this:

```
{
            "metric_value_number": 134,
            "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
            "@timestamp": "2017-02-14T20:36:58.216Z",
            "metric_name": "IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
            "@version": "1",
            "host": "localhost",
            "metric_type": "ReplicaManager",
            "metric_path": "node1.kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
            "type": null,
            "metric_node": "aesdp0101.kafka.server"
          },
{
            "metric_value_number": 134,
            "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
            "@timestamp": "2017-02-14T20:35:58.266Z",
            "metric_name": "IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
            "@version": "1",
            "host": "localhost",
            "metric_type": "ReplicaManager",
            "metric_path": "node1.kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=IsrExpandsPerSec.Count",
            "type": null,
            "metric_node": "aesdp0101.kafka.server"
          }
```

I'm not sure how to do this in javascript natively or if there is a way in lodash to do this as well...

I've tried to do it this way but I think the `_` in `_source` is affecting the code?

```
      var metricData = [];
      for (var i=0; i < response.length; i++) {

         metricData.push(response[i]._source);
         console.log("metric data: ", metricData);

      };
```

Comment: You don't have an array `metricData` anywhere in your question.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include that, I have a `var metricData = []` in the code...made an edit...

Comment: See the below answer, looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to select "hits"?

Try the following:

```
metricData = response.hits.map(hit => hit["_source"])
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that...`TypeError: response.hits.map is not a function`

Comment: What is the response object? You didn't mention this. I suspect you should select json data from it. Or you gave us wrong format of response and "hits" is not an array.

Comment: sorry...typo on my part....again...been along day here....but it worked, thanks so much!